# java simple bank account program

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to build a simple bank account program that that subtract the withdrawal amount from the balance but when I call the **dept** method it's not doing the subtraction.

How to get this program to work, and I'm not sure if I should make the **dept** method void or make it return a value.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class JavaApplication7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        Account account1 = new Account( 50.0 ); 

        System.out.printf( "account1 balance: $%.2f\n", account1.getBalance() );

        double withdrawalAmount;

        System.out.print( "Enter withdrawal amount for account1: " );

        withdrawalAmount = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.printf( "\nsubtracting %.2f from account1 balance\n", withdrawalAmount );

        account1.dept(withdrawalAmount);

        System.out.printf( "account1 balance: $%.2f\n", account1.getBalance() );
    }

}

public class Account {
    private double balance; // instance variable that stores the balance

    public Account( double initialBalance )
    {

        if ( initialBalance > 0.0 )
            balance = initialBalance;
        } 

        public double dept (double dept1){

        dept1=balance-dept1;    
        return dept1;    
    }


    public double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    } 
}
```

Comment: *"hi im trying to.."*  Try to find your shift key.  Apply it at the start of sentences, proper names like Java, & the word I.  Doing so makes text easier to read.  Not doing so makes for text that is like trying to read 'mumbling'.

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dept` method never updates the balance, but instead returns a value you never use.

You should update your balance:

```
public void dept (double dept1){
    balance=balance-dept1;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your debt method return new value of balance but not setting it

what you could do is ie:

```
public void dept (double dept1){
balance-=dept1;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

primitives like double are passed by value, not by reference. You are not changing value outside the debt method.

But yes - you are returning a value, but you don't assign it anywhere - try to assign it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
System.out.println("New Balence is : "+account1.dept(withdrawalAmount));
```

or change this function :

```
public void dept (double dept1){
    balance=balance-dept1;        
    }
```